# Put icon to a XAML ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML. I encountered this problem that **I need to place a symbol icon or font icon into an `Ellipse` shape** (so it shows like an icon inside a circle). However, seems like the Ellipse's `Fill` property only takes `ImageBrush` and `ColorBursh`. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.shape.fill))

How can I add an icon to the Ellipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this (replace your own font symbol in `TextBlock` Text)

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Red"
             Fill="Red"
             StrokeThickness="5">
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock Text="&#xf001;"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to add a font icon or symbol icon instead of a image asset (regarding to my question)?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve something similar using FontIcon:

```
<Button Width="80" Height="80">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource QuantStudioColor}">
                </Ellipse>
                <FontIcon FontSize="16" Glyph="&#xE8E5;" />
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```